# GWT:make text limit on RichTextArea and stop user enter more characters

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT RixhText Area and want to put a limit on 100 characters in the richText Area .

right now i am doing this .

```
                     description.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER ||
                    event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_UP ||
                    event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_LEFT||
                    event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DOWN ||
                    event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE||
                    event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_SHIFT) {

            }else{
            if(description.getText().trim().length()>100){

            Window.alert("You have reached your maximum limit");
            }
            }
        }});
```

Now when 100 characters reached it works fine, give me the alert but how can i stop user from entering more characters , it shows the alert but also takes the input .. how to stop this ..

Secondly I am using this css below to move to the next line itself when area ends.. it works fine .. but if a user just hold down the key on keyboard and don't release this css doesn't works , not taking to next line and goes on .. is there a solution for this

CSS:

```
       break-word {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

thanks

Comment: please split the question into two

Comment: I checked this question on a related issue I had. Just to add some extra help for whoever comes after, I'm doing something similar, but using KeyUpHandler instead of KeyDownHandler, since with the later, when checking the length of the text it seemed to be one character behind (didn't count the char corresponding to the key just pressed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#preventDefault%28%29)  instead of Window.alert()

```
if(description.getText().trim().length()>=100) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Entering characters after 100 you can do somthing like this.

```
if(description.getText().trim().length()>100)
{
        description.setText(description.getText().substring( 0, 100 ));
        Window.alert("You have reached your maximum limit");
}
```

Comment: tried this . it works .. but it disturb all the formating .. like if user was on the 3rd row when he entered 101 word ..then after entering 101st word .text becomes only 1st 100 which is correct but all the complete sentence becomes in one line instead of three lines.. any idea

Comment: Before using the substring you can get the positions of new line character of the text ("\n") and after you substring it you can add \n to the previous positions