# HTML generated for RichTextArea: How to limit no. of characters entered? maxlength?

Tags: jquery, gwt, maxlength, richtextarea

I can see in Chrome/Mozilla/IE Develoer Tools that html generated for GWT's RichTextArea widget is something like this:

```
<iframe class="GCJ2VDKDEI" style="height: 40px; ">
  #document
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>entered text</body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

Can anyone tell me in this kind of text, which is shown under tag, how to access, how to limit no. of characters.I have tried so many things on it but no solution :( basically i want to limit no. of characters so i used jquery functions to get the value but was a failure.

Comment: what are the functions which you tried??

Comment: like i tried using its parent class to find the body tag, but all i got is undefined in the alert used : find, children etc

Comment: I found this link, can anyone help me reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757594/gwtmake-text-limit-on-richtextarea-and-stop-user-enter-more-characters

Comment: I tried these kind of things as well like restricting the keyboard entry http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/restricting-input-with-jquery/ but unfortunate again

Comment: Can you show what you tried, e.g. your GWT code? What exactly do you want to limit? Do you know what you want as the generated html? If so, please show it.

Comment: i want to limit no. of characters. just like max length.

Comment: and this is a embedded html frame.