# Line limit for textarea in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, textarea, limit

I am using GWT textArea in my web application. I have also assigned the `setVisibleLines()` property to my textArea so that I could restrict my user to not enter more then 5 lines of data. I am not able to solve this issue and more lines get added. As I strictly want to restrict number of lines in textarea to be 5 only.

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
textArea.setVisibleLines(5);
```

this is my code. I want this to work like, the user can enter any number of characters on a single line, but he can make entries within 5 lines only and not more than that and once he exceeds 5 lines the user is not able to enter any more characters in the text area. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, add the code.

Comment: I think that actually setVisibleLines means something else compare to what you try to achieve. It sets the number of lines which are visible, but not restrict to enter more.

Comment: Have a look to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757594/gwtmake-text-limit-on-richtextarea-and-stop-user-enter-more-characters

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the method exists for limiting the number of lines, but at least you can restrict the amount of characters inside the textArea by checking

```
yourTextArea.getText().trim().length();
```

Comment: I can have any number of characters/words within those 5 lines